# Android - Changing ImageView position on run-time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Me and my colleague are trying to develop a card game for android.
The cards of a certain player are displayed in the bottom of the screen, and the cards of his opponents are displayed in the top-right and top-left edges of the screen:

http://i39.tinypic.com/i1lhsm.jpg

We would very much like to add the following feature:
When the user clicks one of **his** cards (OnClickListener), the card which he selectes rises a few pixels above the other cards of the player.
If the user selects another card, the previous one returns to his initial position (in the bottom of the screen) and the new card rises.

The entire screen is represented in a RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/game_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#196DBB">


    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/battle_field" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/left_cards"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/left_name">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/right_cards"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/right_name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
     </RelativeLayout>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

The cards which being displayed in the bottom of the screen, are added on runtime, during onCreate:

```
fillLinearLayout(parseAndFillArray(myCardsArray), R.id.game_layout);
```

The implementation of fillLinearLayout is given below:

```
private void fillLinearLayout(LinkedList<Integer> cards, int linearID){
        int myCardsNum = cards.size();
        int cardWidth = (linearID == R.id.game_layout)? cardWidthHorizontal:cardWidthVertical;
        RelativeLayout myCardsLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(linearID);
        if (linearID != R.id.game_layout) myCardsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < myCardsNum ; i++){
            ImageView card = (ImageView)LayoutInflater.from(WelcomeScreen.this).inflate(R.layout.card_view, null);
            card.setImageResource(cards.get(i));
            card.setId(cards.get(i));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)(cardWidth*dp), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (linearID != R.id.game_layout) params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, -1);
            else params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, -1);
            int leftMargin = (linearID == R.id.game_layout)? (int)((i*cardMarginVertical)*dp) : 0;
            int topMargin = (linearID == R.id.game_layout)? 0 : (int)(((i % (10))*cardMarginVertical + 35)*dp);
            int rightMargin = 0;
            int bottomMargin = 0;
            params.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
            card.setLayoutParams(params);
            if (linearID == R.id.game_layout) card.setOnClickListener(OnCardClick(card));
            myCardsLayout.addView(card);
        }
}
```

The cards are glued to the bottom of the screen with the `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, -1)`
code line.

When the user presses a certian card, the onClick function is being called:

```
private View.OnClickListener OnCardClick(final ImageView card)  {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(params.leftMargin, params.topMargin, params.rightMargin, (int)(10*dp));
            }
        };
    }
```

The problem is that this doesn't effect the position of the card being pressed; He just remains in his place.
I guess that the rule ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM is too "strong", and this is why the onClick function doesn't effect the card.
Can anyone think of a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.
For those who would struggle with this in the future:

I have wrapped the ImageView of the card in a RelativeLayout, and put it on a separate layout file under the name my_card_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The cards which being displayed in the bottom of the screen, are added on runtime, during onCreate:

```
fillMyCards(parseAndFillArray(myCardsArray));
```

The implementation of fillMyCards is given below:

```
private void fillMyCards(LinkedList<Integer> cards){
    int size = cards.size();
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_layout);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
        RelativeLayout card = (RelativeLayout)LayoutInflater.from(WelcomeScreen.this).inflate(R.layout.my_card_view, null);
        card.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ImageView cardImage = (ImageView)card.getChildAt(0);
        cardImage.setImageResource(cards.get(i));
        card.setId(cards.get(i));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cardParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        cardParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, -1);
        int leftPadding =(int)((i*cardMarginHorizontal)*dp);
        int topPadding = 0;
        int rightPadding = 0;
        int bottomPadding = 0;
        card.setPadding(leftPadding, topPadding, rightPadding, bottomPadding);
        card.setLayoutParams(cardParams);
        cardImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
        layout.addView(card);
    }
}
```

And now we can change the position of the card by adding the following code to onClick:

```
RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) view.getParent();
parent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, (int)(10*dp));
```